# mysql Query to find the record with best matching row with given value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite

Query to find the record with most matching row with given value

I have a table which is having some value

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  product varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  value1 float NOT NULL,
  value2 float NOT NULL,
  value3 float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

INSERT INTO `product` (`id`, `product`, `value1`, `value2`, `value3`) VALUES
(1, 'test', 5.3, 6.8, 9),
(2, 'test', 8, 9, 12),
(3, 'test', 12, 15, 20),
(4, 'test1', 6, 8, 10),
(5, 'test1', 8, 12, 18),
(6, 'test1', 12, 17, 21);

example

id | product | value1 | value2 | value3 |
1 | test    | 5.3    | 6.8    | 9      |
2 | test    | 8       | 9     | 12     |
3 | test    | 12     | 15     | 20     |
4 | test1  | 6       | 8      | 10     |
5 | test1  | 8       | 12     | 18     |
6 | test1  | 12      | 17     | 21     |

In this, there are two type of product example test and test1 and have some values.
I need to get best matching product of test and test1 by giving value1, value2 and value3|

ex value1=6 value=7 value3=8

In this case I need to get

id | product | value1 | value2 | value3 |
1  | test    | 5.3    | 6.8    | 9      |
4  | test1   | 6      | 8      | 10     |

Please help me to write a mysql query for this.

Comment: Define 'most matching'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your values are some sort of numeric type, you could try doing some sort of query similar to:

```
SELECT *,
  (abs(value1 - targetValue1) +
   abs(value2 - targetValue2) +
   abs(value3 - targetValue3)) AS difference
FROM products
ORDER BY
   difference
```

Where `targetValue1-3` are the product value's you're looking for. If you want only the records who's difference is below some sort of threshold, then you can add a `WHERE difference < threshold`

Comment: In this case I need both test and test1. need result by product.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following solution:

select id, product, value1, value2, value3 
from 
(select id, product, value1, value2, value3,  abs((value1 + value2 + value3) - (6+7+8)) as minimum from t_min  group by id, product) t
group by product;

6+7+8 - are the value1+value2+value3

It contains the sub-select but returns the most matching result separately for test and test1 and what ever other distinct values you might have in the products column.